# OCAML function in parameter of another function

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to pass a function as parameter to another function but I get an error at compilation.

```
Error: This function has type 'a -> 'a -> int
       It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a `;'.
```

My code is:

```
let sort to_do my_list =
        let rec change to_do my_list verify newlist = match my_list with
                | Empty -> if verify = newlist then newlist else
                           change to_do newlist newlist Empty
                | Item (elem, next) -> change to_do my_list verify (compare to_do elem newlist)
        in
        change to_do my_list my_list Empty
;;

let rec compare to_do elem my_list = match my_list with
        | Empty -> (elem, my_list)
        | Item (elem1, Empty) -> if to_do elem elem1 > 0 then Item (elem, elem1) else
                                  Item (elem1, elem)
        | Item (elem1, next) -> compare to_do elem next
;;
```

Comment: Can you include the definition of the type with `Empty` and `Item` variants?

Comment: type 'a my_list = Item of ('a * 'a my_list) | Empty
;;

Comment: Empty is an exivalent of NULL or []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `sort`, you are referring to a function named `compare`. Since the other function `compare` is below, that will be resolved to `Pervasives.compare : 'a -> 'a -> int` (which takes two values and compare them).

Moving your `compare` function above `sort` may fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the person interesting my final code is :

```
 let rec comp to_do elem my_list memlist = match my_list with
         | Empty -> Item (elem, memlist)
         | Item (elem1, Empty) -> if to_do elem1 elem > 0 then Item (elem, memlist) else
                                  rev (Item (elem, (rev memlist)))
         | Item (elem1, next) -> comp to_do elem next memlist
 ;;                                                                                                                                                                                           

 let sort to_do my_list =
         let rec change to_do my_list verify newlist = match my_list with
                 | Empty -> if verify = newlist then newlist else
                            change to_do newlist newlist Empty
                 | Item (elem, next) -> change to_do next verify (comp to_do elem newlist newlist)
         in
         change to_do my_list my_list Empty
 ;;
```